# Why is zu verdanken used in infinite form?

Tags: grammatical-case, verb-usage

In the sentence

> Dies ist vor allen Dingen Ihrem Einsatz zu verdanken.

why the verb *verdanken* is in its "infinitive clause" why was it preceded by *zu* ?

Comment: What makes you doubt about it?

Comment: Would it differ if i removed Zu in the sentence
 Dies ist vor allen Dingen Ihrem Einsatz verdanken

Comment: Yes, _zu_ is needed for the infinite form here. _"Dies ist vor allen Dingen Ihrem Einsatz verdanken"_ doesn't make any sense.

Comment: can you please explain why Zu is needed
i'm sorry but i didn't find any good websitte for expaining this case here
TIA

Comment: A simple google query gives me numerous [results](https://www.google.de/search?q=german+does+zu+belong+to+the+infinitive+form&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiTvMbI7pbaAhVB3qQKHUx6AtwQBQgmKAA&biw=1455&bih=722) to explain that. It's more or less the same as _to_ in  english infinitive forms of verbs.

Answer (score 5):

It is, I think, reasoning ***why*** the "zu" is needed does not lead to very helpful conclusions. This is simply the form to express something like this in German. (For a grammatical analysis of the construct see Hubert's answer.)

One can, however, give various sentences that all are well-formed so you can see the different syntactical options you have to express more or less the same thing.

> Dieser Erfolg ist vor allen Dingen Ihrem Einsatz zu verdanken.
>
> Diesen Erfolg verdanken wir vor allen Dingen Ihrem Einsatz.
>
> Diesen Erfolg verzeichnen wir ausschließlich dank Ihres Einsatzes.
>
> Diesen Erfolg konnten wir ausschließlich dank Ihres außerordentlichen Einsatzes verzeichnen.
>
> Dieser Erfolg verdankt sich Ihrem Einsatz
>
> (Attention, the last one is so unusual that some people may find it even wrong; in my judgement it is technically possible, but awkward.)

Here are some sentences with an opposite message:

> Dieser Misserfolg ist vor allem Ihrer Faulheit geschuldet.
>
> Dieser Misserfolg beruht auf Ihrer Faulheit.

You can also use "verdanken" here, but then your sentence will sound sarcastic:

> Diesen Misserfolg verdanken wir Ihrer Faulheit.
>
> Dieser Misserfolg ist Ihrer Faulheit zu verdanken.

Answer (score 5):

This is a construction that you will find very often in German sentences. The verb is a form of a modal verb and it comes together with the preposition *»zu«* (to) and the infinitive form of another word. In English there is a very similar construction.

> Ich *habe* viel *zu tun.*
>   I *have* much *to do.*

And in your sentence there is this construction:

> Dies *ist* Ihrem Einsatz *zu verdanken.*
>   This *is* your efforts *to thank*. (word order as in German)
>   This is thanks to your efforts. (better English)

Comment: The "to" in "thanks to your efforts" is now a preposition, though.